# How do I set user field in form to the currently logged in user?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I'm making an election information app, and I want to allow the currently logged-in user to be able to declare himself *and only* himself as a candidate in an election.

I'm using Django's built-in ModelForm and CreateView. My problem is that the Run for Office form (in other words, the 'create candidate' form) allows the user to select *any* user in the database to make a candidate.

I want the user field in the Run for Office to be automatically set to the currently logged-in user, and for this value to be hidden, so the logged-in user cannot change the value of the field to someone else.

**views.py**

```
class CandidateCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Candidate
    form_class = CandidateForm
    template_name = 'candidate_create.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        f = form.save(commit=False)
        f.save()
        return super(CandidateCreateView, self).form_valid(form)
```

**forms.py**

```
class CandidateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Candidate
```

**models.py**

```
class Candidate(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile)
    office = models.ForeignKey(Office)
    election = models.ForeignKey(Election)
    description = models.TextField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.user)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('candidate_detail', kwargs={'pk': str(self.id)})
```

Answer (score 60, accepted):

1. Remove user field from rendered form (using `exclude` or `fields`, https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#selecting-the-fields-to-use )

   ```
   class CandidateForm(forms.ModelForm):
       class Meta:
           model = Candidate
           exclude = ["user"]
   ```
2. Find user profile and set user field in the create view.

   ```
   class CandidateCreateView(CreateView):
       ...
       def form_valid(self, form):
           candidate = form.save(commit=False)
           candidate.user = UserProfile.objects.get(user=self.request.user)  # use your own profile here
           candidate.save()
           return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
   ```

Comment: Dang, that was easy. I was trying things like "candidate.user = self.request.user" before, but obviously that doesn't work. This will come in handy for other forms I have to make, thanks a lot!

Comment: Why is candidate.user = self.request.user not a working ? Isn't self.request.user   a user object too ?

Comment: Because self.request.user is User instance, but Candidate.user is UserProfile instance.

Comment: This approach will integrate user into form itself http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4141408/django-form-set-current-login-user

Comment: I am using crispy form.  I have to changed the last line to 'return super(CanndidateCreateView, self).form_valid(form)' in order for the redirect to work.

Comment: Is it possible to make a Mixin from it ? I would like to reuse the form_valid you just made in several create views.

Answer (score 8):

### Assumptions

1. We don't want to set `null=True` becaues we don't want to allow `null` users at the model and/or database level
2. We don't want to set `blank=True` to mess with the readability of model because the user actually will not be blank

**@nbm.ten** solution is a good one. It has an advantages over other 'solutions'to this problem that utilized **model** to set the user (like [this one](https://djangopatterns.readthedocs.io/en/latest/models/automatically_filling_user.html)) in  nbm.ten's doesn't undermine the assumptions above. We don't want to mess with the model to fix a problem in view!

But here I add two other solutions based on django documentation ([Models and request.user](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/#models-and-request-user)):

### Two other solutions

#### 1. Using  the generic CreateView

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView
from myapp.models import Candidate

class CandidateCreate(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Candidate
    exclude = ['user']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.user = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

#### 2. Using class-based views

```
class CandidateForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Candidate
        exclude = [ 'user',]

class CandidateAddView(LoginRequiredMixin, View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = CandidateForm()
        context = {'form':form}
        return render(request, 'myapp/addcandidateview.html', context)
    
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
           
        form = CandidateForm(request.POST)
        form.instance.user = request.user
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect(reverse('myapp:index'))
```

### NOTES

- Note that **`LoginRequiredMixin`** prevents users who aren’t logged in from accessing the form. If we omit that, we'll need to handle unauthorized users in `form_valid()` or `post()`.
- Also `exclude = ['user']` prevents the user field to be shown on the form.
- We used `form.instance.user` to set the user not `form.data` or `form.cleaned_data` they don't work

Comment: You should probably mention that the "generic create view" is a class based view that does all the work you're doing in what you call a "class based view", only with more abstractions and sane defaults.