# How can I update the details of current user using forms and views

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

I am new to django, I an updating my userprofile models using forms and view,I need to get the current user who is logged in and I need to update the details for that user

`forms.py`

```
class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta: 
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ('gender','email_id','mobile_number','date_of_birth')
```

`View.py`

```
def update_UserProfile_views(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
       form = ProfileForm(request.POST)
       if form.is_valid():
          profile = form.save(commit=False)
          profile.save()
    else:
        form = ProfileForm()
    return render(request, 'base.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18247059/3224008

Comment: Which name are you looking for? `request.user` gives you the user..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can create a instance and get user name

```
def update_UserProfile_views(request):
    try:
        current_user = request.user
        user = UserProfile.objects.get(user_name=current_user)
    except Exception:
        return render(request, 'base.html', {})
    else:
        if request.method == "POST":
            form = ProfileForm(request.POST,instance=user)
            if form.is_valid():
                profile = form.save(commit=False)
                profile.save()
        else:
            form = ProfileForm()
        return render(request, 'base.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: OP said "user name", but that isn't what they want. They want the actual UserProfile, which they can just get from `request.user.userprofile` assuming it has a one-to-one relationship with User.