# Display a different default value in Django CreateView according to current logged in user?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, modelform

Long story short, I am creating a ModelForm which will be passed to a generic CreateView. This form will allow a user to post an event with a location. I have already collected the user's base address in my user creation form, and my Event model has a foreignkey to the author of the event.

I would like to display the city and state of the currently logged in user as a default value on the event creation form. Since default values are set at the model level, I am not able to use the requests framework. Solution such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18246326/in-django-how-do-i-set-user-field-in-form-to-the-currently-logged-in-user) offer a way to save info from the request to the database upon submission but I would like to display this default when the user first navigates to the form page. How do I achieve this functionality?

**Edit** I would like to be able to pass an initial parameter as in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/604266/django-set-default-form-values) but have it dynamically determined by the current logged in user.

Here is the essential part of the model. Note that BusinessUser has city and state fields.

```
class Job(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(BusinessUser, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, help_text="If different from the location listed on your company profile.")
```

And here is the view so far:

```
class JobCreation(LoginRequiredMixin, SuccessMessageMixin, generic.edit.CreateView):
    model = Job
    form_class = JobCreationForm
    context_object_name = 'job'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('jobs:business_profile')
    success_message = 'New job posted!'

def form_valid(self, form):
    form.instance.author = self.request.user
    return super().form_valid(form)
```

JobCreationForm is the work in progress that I'm stuck on. At the moment, it's a ModelForm giving the model and fields.

```
class JobCreationForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Job
        fields = (
            'job_title',
            'location',         
        )
```

Comment: Updated with code

Comment: As an aside, I'm not sure what `get_object` is meant to do here - `CreateView` doesn't need a `get_object` method because the object hasn't been created yet.

Comment: Gotcha, I thought the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override [`get_initial`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormMixin.get_initial) if you want to set initial data dynamically. If you don't need to set it dynamically you can simply set `initial`.

```
class JobCreation(LoginRequiredMixin, SuccessMessageMixin, generic.edit.CreateView):
    model = Job
    form_class = JobCreationForm

    def get_initial(self):
        initial = super().get_initial()
        initial['location'] = self.request.user.location
        return initial

    ...
```

Comment: Works for me. I'm actually using a User model that just defines the user type and then extending that model to get BusinessUser (which is where I add details like city and state). So, I had to do something like: `user_info = BusinessUser.objects.get(pk=self.request.user.pk)` and then access the city and state fields from `user_info` with `initial['location'] = user_info.city + ", " + user_info.state`. I wouldn't think the standard use case needs this quibble so I'll leave the question as is if you agree.