# 'WSGIRequest' Error when trying to create Model object based on username for logged in User

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

## AIM

I am attempting to set the `Alarm.username` to the username of the currently logged in `User`. The problem is identical to [another query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4141408/django-form-set-current-login-user), although my code is a little different in that I extract location details for each `Alarm` object.

How,and where, do I integrate the line:  `username=User.objects.get(username=self.request.username)` in my code?

## ERROR

```
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://jqlc3gdp.apps.lair.io/login/set_alarm/
Django Version: 2.0
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:    
'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'username'
Exception Location: /mnt/project/weather_alarm/views.py in get_user_timezone, line 94
```

## CODE

**Models.py**

```
class User(models.Model):
    """ Model representing each User """
    username = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=30, validators=[MinLengthValidator(8)])
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=254)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)


class Alarm(models.Model):
    """ Model representing each Alarm """
    alarm_id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    username = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)         # null=True is TEMP
    timezone = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    time = models.DateTimeField()
    temp_conditional = models.BooleanField()
    surf_conditional = models.BooleanField()
    temp_max = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    temp_min = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    surf_max = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    surf_min = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
```

**Forms.py**

```
class SetAlarmForm(ModelForm):
    ...    
    class Meta:
        model = Alarm
        exclude = ['username', 'timezone', 'city', 'country']
```

**Views.py**

```
class AlarmCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Alarm
    form_class = SetAlarmForm
    template_name = 'weather_alarm/set_alarm.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('weather_alarm:confirm-alarm')
    login_url = "/login/"

    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.get_user_location(form)
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def get_user_location(self, form):
        """ Function to get User's location from IP and create Alarm object """
        ...
        alarm_object = Alarm.objects.create(
            alarm_id=uuid.uuid4(),
            username=User.objects.get(username=self.request.username),
            timezone=user_timezone,
            city=location.raw['address']['city'],
            country=location.raw['address']['country'],
            time=form.cleaned_data['time'].astimezone(pytz.timezone(user_timezone)),
            temp_conditional=form.cleaned_data['temp_conditional'],
            surf_conditional=form.cleaned_data['surf_conditional'],
            temp_max=form.cleaned_data['temp_max'],
            temp_min=form.cleaned_data['temp_min'],
            surf_max=form.cleaned_data['surf_max'],
            surf_min=form.cleaned_data['surf_min'],
        )
        alarm_object.save()
```

Comment: `self.request.username`, first of all the request object doesn't have the attribute called `username`, hence your error. Also you're using ForeignKey for the username field in Alram Model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be `self.request.user.username`:

```
username = User.objects.get(username=self.request.user.username)
```

Or since `request.user` already contains current user object better to use:

```
username = self.request.user
```

Comment: I tried that and get the following error: `Exception Type: DoesNotExist. Exception Value: User matching query does not exist.`

Comment: @ycrad did you set `AUTH_USER_MODEL`? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model

Comment: @Thomas Thanks for edit, but can you please explain why you remove `username = self.request.user` part?

Comment: I explained in the edit message: `username` is a CharField, `self.request.user` is a LazyLoaded User object. Assigning one to the other relies on implicit conversion through `Model.__unicode__()` and should not be considered stable, is definitely not something you should be teaching new django programmers. I've personally had a lot of trouble with LazyLoad user objects with the ORM in the past. Stick to assigning strings to CharFields and you won't get any weird, hard to debug issues in the future.

Comment: @Thomas Thank you. But username is ForeignKey in Alarm model, not CharField. So assigning shouldn't give any problem in this situation. Or I missed something?

Comment: You are correct, I was the one missing something. In which case, your first suggestion is the wrong one, and the second one is right.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I amended to `username=self.request.user` as suggested, but am getting the following error: `ValueError: Cannot assign "<SimpleLazyObject: <User: alarm_admin>>": "Alarm.username" must be a "User" instance.` Is it because I haven't set up `AUTH_USER_MODEL` as suggested?

Comment: @ycrad yes, by default Django using builtin User model.