# ValueError when attempting to create Model object based on username for logged in User

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

## AIM

I am attempting to create an `Alarm` object with the `user` field set as the username for the logged in `User`.

The issue identical to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51717710/wsgirequest-error-when-trying-to-create-model-object-based-on-username-for-log/51717771?noredirect=1#comment90435691_51717771) I asked recently. However, I restructured **models.py** and `user=self.request.user.username` is now returning the error stated below.

Despite the fact that I am now using Django's default User model, is the reason why `self.request.user.username` isn't working is because I haven't set up `AUTH_USER_MODEL`?

## ERROR

```
ValueError: Cannot assign "'sam_jones'": "Alarm.user" must be a "User" instance.
```

## CODE

**Models.py**

```
class Alarm(models.Model):
    """ Model representing each Alarm """
    alarm_id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    timezone = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    time = models.DateTimeField()
    temp_conditional = models.BooleanField()
    surf_conditional = models.BooleanField()
    temp_max = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    temp_min = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    surf_max = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    surf_min = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.alarm_id)
```

**Views.py**

```
class AlarmCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    """ CreateView for User to create the Alarm object """
    model = Alarm
    ...

    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.get_user_location(request, form)
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def get_user_location(self, request, form):
        """ Function to get Profile's location from IP and create Alarm object """
        ...
        alarm_object = Alarm.objects.create(
            alarm_id=uuid.uuid4(),
            user=self.request.user.username,
            ...
        )
        alarm_object.save()
```

Comment: Try using self.request.user instead of self.request.user.username

Comment: I have tried `self.request.user` and get the following error: `UNIQUE constraint failed: weather_alarm_alarm.user_id`.

Comment: Then maybe user is not logged in

Comment: @ycrad see my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to provide **User** instance, which is avalibale on **`request.user`** attribute. So try this

```
alarm_object = Alarm.objects.create(
            alarm_id=uuid.uuid4(),
            user=self.request.user,
            ...
        )
```

You could do this also by reffering their **`id`** as,

```
alarm_object = Alarm.objects.create(
            alarm_id=uuid.uuid4(),
            user=self.request.user.id,
            ...
        )
```

**`UNIQUE constraint failed`** exception raised because you defined `user` field as **`OneToOneField`** to `User` model, which means For every `Alarm` instance are related to **ATMOST one User**.